# How to print parameters along with sql generated by Hibernate 5.4 using log4j2.properties file

Tags: hibernate, log4j2

Following is the content of my `log4j2.properties` file. It prints the sql but does not print the parameters. How do I add `org.hibernate.type=trace` or similar to print the parameters?

```
appenders = console, file
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
 
appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = File
appender.file.fileName = app.log
appender.file.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
 
rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
rootLogger.appenderRef.file.ref = File
 
logger.hibernate.name=org.hibernate.SQL
logger.hibernate.level=debug
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add just one more logger:

```
logger.hibernate-type.name=org.hibernate.type
logger.hibernate-type.level=trace
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution works perfectly. So, i am assuming, for other  Hibernate log categories, first I need to assign the category to a name and then set the level! for example: 

logger.hibernate-transaction.name=org.hibernate.transaction
logger.hibernate-transaction.level=debug

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers I saw regarding this problem worked for me. I had to set

```
rootLogger.level = trace
```

in my log4j2.properties to see the parameter bindings. Although this makes the entire logs quite verbose, at least it works.